# Does Uncle Tat Play the Same Character in God of Gambler 1 and 2?

Tags: god-of-gamblers

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_of_Gamblers

This one says that he plays "Brother Sing"

In God of Gamblers 2, he plays as uncle of the protagonist.

Is this the same character?

If I look at the cast it says

Ng Man-tat as (花柳成) Brother Shing

So Ng Man Tat plays as Brother Shing. Shing seems to be the name of the saint of gambler.

So, is this the same or related character with Shing's uncle in God of Gamblers 2?

It seems that they're playing different character. The character in god of gamblers 1 is just a mafia boss. The character in god of gamblers 2 is Sing's uncle. Still, they could be the same guy. Sing's uncle can be a mafia boss in god of gamblers 1. Can people check

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_of_Gamblers#Gamblers_franchise

Comment: Yea I read that. It seems that they're playing different character. The character in god of gamblers 1 is just a mafia boss. The character in god of gamblers 2 is Sing's uncle. Still, they could be the same guy. Sing's uncle can be a mafia boss in god of gamblers 1.

Can people check